# NetBeans erro: pacote org não existe

Tags: java, netbeans

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para desktop utilizando o netbeans. Passei alguns meses sem mexer no projeto, e quando volto a abri-lo me aparece a mensagem que o pacote org não existe. Já deletei a pasta Cache do Netbeans, já atualizei, atualizei o java e nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Apos reiniciar a IDE o problema continua. O interessante que o erro é somente na classe principal, nas demais classes nao tem erro. Será que preciso refazer toda essa clase do 0 utilizando layout relativo?

[image: erro]

---

[image: erro]

Comment: Que pacote org? Adicione o eerro exatamente como aparece pra você na pergunta.

Comment: Qual versão do JDK do seu projeto?

Comment: esta na versao jdk1.8.0_65

Comment: Cheque se adicionou a lib abaixo corretamente, veja se ela está no classpath do projeto correto. Não era pro erro está acontecendo após adiciona-la, a classe citada está na lib que eu indiquei pra adição.

Comment: Mano o classpathda biblioteca esta vazio, nao tem nada.. enquanto outras tem o diretorio. Iai?

Comment: Adiciona a lib da resposta. O erro vai sumir somente quando a lib for adicionada no classpath. Olhe nas propriedades do seu projeto, o procedimento é parecido com o da resposta.

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte maneira: Baixei novamente o classpath da biblioteca aqui: http://www.docjar.com/jar/AbsoluteLayout.jar e importei pra minha biblioteca AbsoluteLayout. Ta funfando de boa agora.

Comment: Menos mal então :) Mas é bem estranho isso, a lib do netbeans é a mesma dessa ai que você baixou a parte. Até simulei o problema aqui, removendo a lib, o projeto deu os mesmos erros que no seu, depois adicionei e voltou ao normal. Tente reinstalar seu netbeans ou baixar a versão mais recente(8.1) pra evitar esse problema no futuro.

Comment: Ja tinha instalado a versao mais recente pra tentar solucionar e nada.. o unico jeito foi esse kk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheque se no classpath do seu projeto, há a lib `AbsoluteLayout`, ela é adicionada automaticamente toda vez que você cria um projeto java no netbeans(pelo menos até a versão jdk 7).

Expanda seu projeto e clique com o botão direito na pasta **Libraries**. Depois clique na opção **Add Library**,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e selecione `AbsoluteLayout` na lista.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, a lib deve ficar desta forma no seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz o que propos, consigo seguir todos os passos, porem a biblioteca nao é adicionada. Precisa reiniciar o netbeans apos a adiçao da biblioteca?

Comment: Só isso já resolve o problema, mas se seu projeto não estiver configurado para compilar automaticamente, ou você pode simplesmente executar o projeto.